# use of 'respectively'

Tags: word-usage

It is okay to say

> A and B correspond to C and D, respectively.

But, is it okay to say

> They correspond to C and D, respectively?

Here implicitly it is assumed that 'they' represents 'A and B'. The concern is that, it could also be 'B and A'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use

> respectively

there needs to be a 1-to-1 correspondence between the two lists so the match in the proper ordering.  Your sentence as it stands

> They correspond to C and D, respectively.

is ambiguous, however with additional context

> A and B are managers at the company.
>   They correspond to C and D, respectively.

A would be paired with C and B would be paired with D.

Comment: Should the words in the first list connected using `and` or could I use `or`. For example: `A or B correspond to C and D, respectively.` ?